# Make a User only view and manage users in setup - Nothing else

Tags: security, permission-sets, user-management

Is there a way - setting to say that a user will only manage users (view, create and update users) from setup and nothing else? For example, i don't want this user to have access to object manager from setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible. A user needs to have View Setup & Configuration in order to see the User Detail page and related User settings (e.g. User List Views). This permission will also allow users to see the Object Manager, although they would need additional permissions to create/update/delete/truncate fields and objects.

Comment: sfdcfox, thank you very much for your response. I also created a Custom web tab to navigate user directly from App Launcher to Manage users. Of course, this does not change what you said. Still the user need to have "View Setup and Configuration" Permission.